# Compile Solution without DLL's Visual Studio Managed C++

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, managed-c++

I'm very new at C++ Managed and Visual Studio keep this in mind. Ive programmed an application that makes it easy for users to bind keys in counterstrike, found here:
https://sites.google.com/site/intrepidprojects/

The first error I ran into with my friends testing the program was "msvcr120D.dll is missing". Which lead me to finding that I have to set the runtime library to Multi-threaded (/MTd), if I don't want the users to download the Visual Studio c++ dll's . When I choose this option I was given the error that /MTd and /clr are incompatible. So I turned the common runtime support to no support. Now all of the namespaces are invalid such as 'System', 'Collections', etc.

My question is how do I produce a stand alone application without needing the dll's? Every solution I have come across leads me to more errors I do not understand. 
Again, the language I am using is c++/cli. Sorry If I am not using the proper lingo to communicate my errors I am teaching this on my own.I am aware that this question has been asked many times before, but the answers are not leading me to solutions.

Comment: You can't. You're already forcing users to deploy the .NET framework. Deploying the VC redist isn't difficult after you've solved the first problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*My question is how do I produce a stand alone application without needing the dll's?* basically: you don't. Just have them install the [CRT runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) - the'll need it anyway sooner or later as you're not the only one writing programs targetting that toolset (btw, you tagged the question VS2012 but those dlls are normally for VS2013?). As an alternative you could look for all the needed dlls (msvcr120.dll, msvcp120.dll etc, use Dependency Walker) on your filesystem and put them in the same directory as your executable, that works as well because of how the path is searched for dlls. But it's a bit messy.

Furtermore missing msvcr120D means you are building your project with the Debug configuration (that is what the D stands for), but you should build with Release configuration when shipping to users as the runtime installer only installs release versions.

Answer (score 1):

Select MT without DLL in VC++/C Code generation section in solution properties. Worked for me.